# Recommendations for preventing data leakage in Random Forest Regressor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am currently getting 1.00 for both accuracy and f1 measurement. I suspect that it is as a result of data leakage.

I'm looking for any tips to reduce data leakage as far as possible.

Thanks.

Bellow is my python script:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
# Other imports here
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset = pd.read_csv("weather.csv")  

print(len(dataset))

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["Date", "Location", "WindGustDir", "WindDir9am", "WindDir3pm",])

dataset["RainToday"] = dataset["RainToday"].map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
dataset["RainTomorrow"] = dataset["RainTomorrow"].map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})

dataset.dropna(inplace=True)

dataset = dataset.rename_axis(None)

X = dataset.drop('RainTomorrow', axis=1)

y = dataset['RainTomorrow']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=216037514)

classifier = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 200, random_state = 216037514)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print("Report:\n", classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print("Accuracy:  ", accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

Current results:

```
142193
Report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00      9026
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00      2592

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11618
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11618
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11618

Accuracy:   1.0
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the columns `RainToday` and `RainTomorrow`? Do you have the 4 configurations `Yes/Yes`, `No/No`, `Yes/No` and `No/Yes` appearing?

Comment: Is it a time-series dataset? If so, your problem lies in the train_test_split part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source on data leakage: https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/

> Data leakage can cause you to create overly optimistic if not completely invalid predictive models.

Assuming this is a real data set, classification scores of 1.0 are rather unrealistic. Thus, data leakage appears to be a plausible explanation here.

The source above suggests two general techniques to guard against data leakage:

> 1. Perform data preparation within your cross validation folds.
> 2. Hold back a validation dataset for final sanity check of your developed models.

These are good suggestions. I'd like to add a third:

3. Know your data!

Look at the data, think about the data, then look at it again. Then look from a different angle. If possible, open it in a text editor. Print the data frame. Plot the data. Do whatever you can think of to get a feel for it. Ask yourself the following questions:

- **Are there duplicate rows?** You don't want duplicates. They totally defeat the purpose of cross-validation and hold-out sets.
- **Are there duplicate columns?** Some algorithms don't like colinear variables and you don't want your target variable to sneak into the feature variables.
- **Is there any information in the features that should not causally be there?** For example, if today you predict tomorrow's rain there should be no information about tomorrow that is not available today.
- **Are the rows not independent?** or
- **Does the data have correlations within groups?** If yes, make sure each group is either in the test set or in the train set but never in both. Scikit-learn has functions for that, such as [`GroupKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold). Groups can enter a data set in many weird ways; examples are repeated measurements, changed measurement devices/methods, measurements close in time or space, ...

Once you are certain the data is fine validate your processing:

- Randomly shuffle the column(s) that contain the target variable(s). Do that as early as possible in the processing chain (i.e. modify the .csv file, or do it as soon as the column is constructed). Make sure *only* that column is shuffled.

I affectionately call this the garbage test. It turns data into garbage that almost makes sense. If the model still gives "good" results go looking for the mistake in code or concept.